# How to trigger events upon the completion of a best_in_place edit?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, best-in-place

In the show page, I display a list of dates of the occurrence of a periodic event, and statistics calculated ver all the dates such as max, min, and average interval between successive dates.

I use the best_in_place gem to allow in-place editing of the dates. However, each time a date is changed, the statistics must be calculated and re-rendered from the server.

How do I hook a callback function to the completion of the best_in_place edit, so that the stats can be re-rendered?

This is my Rails code in show.html.erb

```
<td id="event_date">
  <%= best_in_place @event, :occur_date %>
</td>
```

which in html is

```
<td id="event_date"> 
    <span class='best_in_place' id='best_in_place_event_132_occur_date' data-url='/events/132' data-object='event' data-attribute='occur_date' data-type='input'>2012-03-23</span>
</td>
```

I tried the following coffee script code:

```
jQuery ->
$("#best_in_place_event_*_occur_date").live 'ajax:complete', (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
  alert "a date has changed"
```

This doesn't seem to work, nothing happens after I edit a date (occur_date).

Anyone knows how I should trigger an event upon a successful best_in_place edit?

Comment: You say, "statistics must be calculated and re-rendered from the server." So this recalculation happens in the model and is called from the controller in the update action, right? Just trying to get my facts straight before answering.

Comment: Yes, the stats calculation is done in the model, and the stats (e.g. max, min, avg) aren't stored in ActiveRecord. Not sure if I'm doing it right, but I don't go through the controller,I have the view calls the model method.  Here are my codes.  In `views/events/show.html.erb`          <%= render :partial => "events_stats", :locals => {:event => @event}%>  
And in `views/events/_event_stats.html.erb`: 
<% stats = event.get_event_stats%>
<% if stats%> <b> shortest:</b><%= stats[:min] %> days <b> longest: </b><%= stats[:max] %> days <b> average: </b><%= stats[:average] %> days
<% end %>

Answer (score 2):

Well, looking at the source, it seems like best_in_place correctly fires the ajax:success event in it's loadSuccessCallback. That means you should be able to bind your own functions to the changed event with some jQuery.

```
$(".best_in_place").live 'change', (event) ->
  alert "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: This works great. Just be sure to substitute jquery's "live" method with the newer "on" method.

Comment: Right, @Stone. Karen was using `live` in her question, she didn't show a parent element I could use with `on`, and also it's an old answer.

Comment: Totally, just wanted to put that there to inform anyone looking at the answer now. Thanks for your answer btw!

Answer (score 1):

as for your example:

```
<td id="event_date">
  <%= best_in_place @event, :occur_date, :classes => 'bip_date' %>
</td>

$('.bip_date').bind("ajax:success", function(){
alert("a date has changed")
});
// or: $('.event_data .best_in_place').bind(...)
```

And from the [official readme](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place#binding-to-ajaxsuccess):

> The 'ajax:success' event is triggered upon success.
>
> Use bind:

```
$('.best_in_place').bind("ajax:success", function ()
{$(this).closest('tr').effect('highlight'); });
```

> To bind a callback that is specific to a particular field, use the
>   'classes' option in the helper method and then bind to that class.
>
> ```
> <%= best_in_place @user, :name, :classes => 'highlight_on_success' %>
> <%= best_in_place @user, :mail, :classes => 'bounce_on_success' %>
>
> $('.highlight_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function(){bip_date});
> $('.bounce_on_success').bind("ajax:success", function(){$(this).closest('tr').effect('bounce'));});
> ```